# Javascript in Chrome not compatible with Firefox Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I made a search engine which works with javascript instead of being backend with sql queries. It works fine in Chrome but it doesn't work on firefox. I thought pure javascript would be compatible with all navigators. Could someone tell me which part is being refused by firefox.

I am trying to duplicate this search engine in JQuery as jquery makes everything compatible with eachother, but i am having some trouble with the each() function. I am new to JQuery.

**The logic is :**

The CMS auto-creates the content on the page about country related documents. 
 The auto generated code looks like:

[image]

So i target the class "csc-firstheader" which contains the reference to the country, and get its parent's parent and make it's css property display = 'none'

**The script is as follows**

```
               <script type="text/javascript">
               function filterByCountry(){
                 var inputField = document.getElementById('search-field');
                 var string = inputField.value;
                 if(string!=""){        
                  var headers =  document.getElementsByClassName('csc-firstHeader');
                  var errorMessage = document.getElementById('failure-message');
                        errorMessage.style.display = "none";
                  var exist=0;
                        for(var i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
                                if( headers[i].innerText.toLowerCase() !=                    string.toLowerCase() ){
                                    var header = headers[i]; 
                                    header = header.parentNode;
                                    header = header.parentNode;
                                    header = header.parentNode;
                                    header.style.display = "none";
                                    header.style.position = "relative";
                                    header.style.top = "0px";
                                    header.style.left = "0px";
                                    header.style.width = "292px";
                                }
                                if( headers[i].innerText.toLowerCase() ==                                                          string.toLowerCase() ){
                                     exist=1;
                                    var header = headers[i]; 
                                    header = header.parentNode;
                                    header = header.parentNode;
                                    header = header.parentNode;
                                    header.style.display = "inline-block";
                                    header.style.position = "absolute";
                                    header.style.top = "110px";
                                    header.style.left = "48px";
                                    header.style.width = "482px";

                                }
                        }
                    if(exist == 0){
                        errorMessage.style.display = "inline-block";
                    }
                    }

               </script>
```

**The search bar is :**

```
                    <div id="search-container">
                        <input type="text" id="search-field"  placeholder="search a specific country" />
                        <button id="search-button" onclick="filterByCountry()" > Search </button>



                 </div>
```

**The JFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/arj196/5RkLL/

Comment: The main part of your question has nothing to do with jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support the `innerText` property.

You should use `textContent` instead for Firefox (and all browsers which support it, as this is the standard W3C property). You can check for both like this:

```
var header = headers[i];
var headerText = header.textContent || header.innerText;
if( headerText.toLowerCase() == string.toLowerCase() ){
```

Other than that, I don't see any other functions or properties which aren't supported by most major browsers. For reference, you can have a look in the error console on the browser which doesn't work - it should show something like `Cannot call function "toLowerCase" on undefined`. That tells you that `innerText` is undefined. Then you can Google to see which browsers support that property.

Comment: Thanks alot! The console trick did what you predicted. 

There is some problem, now for some reason the if condition is not working, i am updating the question. Adding jfiddle to the question so it will be easier to debug